# How to read the value returned by an AJAX response

Tags: jquery

Sorry for the vague title but I'm not sure how to phrase this question.

How do I get the value of a non-element? I want to send a value into a function that is not a class or id.

This is normally how I'm used to getting a value within a function but in this case, I want to send a string into the function. How is this done? Can someone please provide an example?

```
var url = $('#url').val();
```

Something along these lines:

```
var url = mystring.val();
```

Comment: So just to be clear, you want to call index.php while staying on the current page and then go somewhere else based on the server's response? Is it possible to have the call to index.php *return* the somewhere else?

Comment: @jim, I edited your post for better reading, but I guess you did not like it... Anyway, about your problem, is `'http://forward.somewhere.com?url=' + url` somewhat what you want?

Comment: Hi Dan, yes, that's correct. There is absolutely no other place I can have the call go to; it must be in the index.php page.

Comment: @Reigel, Yes, that is what I want but I first need to set the url value. This is where I'm stuck because it needs to be a string and is not an element id. I've edited my post yet again to show this.

Comment: @jim I've edited the title to make it easier for other people with the same problem to find a solution. Could you please add more context to your question. I noticed that some example code had been added in earlier revisions, but they've been removed now.

Comment: @jim, is `$('#url').val();` returning you an element value??

Answer (score 1):

An ajax response can contain text, json, xml, or whatever other format you want, and jQuery facilitates this. How you implement the entire end-to-end communication is dependent on what you're using for server-side stuff.

Check out [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I'll have a look now.

Comment: Stefan, I'm a bit confused on what I need. I'm going to post the ajax function above with a little more info

Comment: I usually hate to say "RTM", but the examples are jQuery.com really are quite good. If you describe what server language you're using and what you'd like to send back, that could get you a more thorough answer I think. Scroll down to the bottom of the jQuery.ajax page for real examples of how to use the function.

Comment: if you look at the example I posted, you can clearly see that url: points to `index.php` which would indicate that it is more than likely PHP. I've already read the manual but I can't see how to do what I want.